# Prevent removing field in json if field is empty and field is required angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I was wondering if theres any way to prevent removing the field in json.

for example i have a form:

```
<form name="frmSample">
<input type="text" required ng-model="user.firstname" />
<input type="text" ng-model="user.lastname" />
</form>
```

so if field is not empty the object will be {"firstname":"not empty","lastname":"not empty"}
but what i need is to make it like this when empty: {"firstname":"","lastname":""} even if they are required, not {"lastname":""}

is it posible?

thanks

Comment: `$scope.user = {firstname: "", lastname: ""}` in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could set the values in your controller like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')      
   .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

   // ...

   $scope.user = {
       firstname: '',
       lastname: '',
   };

   // ...

});
```

Incidentally, it's the `required` attribute on the `user.firstname` input field that's causing the `firstname` property to become `undefined`. If you remove the `required` attribute, your problem goes away:

```
<form name="frmSample">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstname" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastname" />
</form>
```

Comment: thank your for your reply. but what i need is when you clear the first_name field the first_name key in json should retain. try my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasonv/Vsa2N/2/

Comment: You could do this: $scope.$watch('user.first_name',function(){ if($scope.user.first_name === undefined){ $scope.user.first_name = ""; } });

Comment: Alternatively, just remove the 'required' attribute from the first_name input. If an empty string is acceptable input, then it's not really required anyway. http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDeLaGhetto/7R68q/1/